# How to use array_combine along with str_replace in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, replace, str-replace

I am doing some array combine in php. But while combining/mapping the key of one array to value of another array i want to do some string replace in the value of the array which is going to be combined. How to use `str_replace` along with `array_combine` in php. **Mostly without `forloop`.**

Eg:

```
$a1 = array("35","37","43");
$a2 = array("Testing's", "testing's", "tessting's");
```

Normal combine is like below, (i.e) removing `'` in those string while combine.

```
$a3 = array_combine($a1, $a2);
```

Output i want is like below,

```
array(
    35 => "Testing",
    37 => "testing",
    43 => "tessting"
)
```

Comment: [`str_replace()` will happily receive an array.](https://3v4l.org/MZ1uq)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Then after combining them, you could use `array_map` on the resultant array:

```
$a3 = array_map(function($e){
    return str_replace("'s", '', $e);
}, array_combine($a1, $a2)); // anonymous function PHP 5.4 or greater
```

Comment: How can i parse the single, double quotes and other characters in from csv file data while parsing those datas in php?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that :

```
function cust_replace($n)
    {
        return  str_replace("'s","",$n);
    }
    $a1 = array("35","37","43");
    $a2 = array("Testing's", "testing's", "tessting's");
    $a3 = array_map("cust_replace",array_combine($a1, $a2));
    print_r($a3);
```

If you want to make it more generic, you can add another parameter to cust_replace - the "needle" you want to replace.